# How to fetch release details of all releases between two release definitions using Azure DevOps REST API?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-releases

The requirement is to fetch the release details as a list or at least the **release IDs of all releases between two given release version**. For example, assume latest release is "Release-10" and the requirement is to fetch the release data of all release from say "Release-5" to "Release-10".

To fetch release data of a particular release, below API can be used.

```
GET https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/releases/{releaseId}?api-version=6.0
```

So, if we have the release ID's of all releases between base release ID and latest release ID, data can be fetched using above API call. Is it possible to fetch these details using Azure DevOps REST API?

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with PowerShell you can use the [AzurePipelinesPS](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzurePipelinesPS/4.0.7) module and the command below to return all the release details for a project. Out-GridView takes those details and passes them to a table for easy filtering.

```
Get-APReleaseList -Session $session | Out-GridView -PassThru
```

The command below requires a release id that you can get from the previous command.

```
Get-APRelease -Session $session -ReleaseId 'your_release_id'
```

The module supports "sessions" to limit the number of required parameters. See the module's [github page](https://github.com/Dejulia489/AzurePipelinesPS) on how to create a session.